# PDO custom class and security

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to create my own class to work/play with database with PDO. I am having the following method in my class:

```
private function connect(){
    try{
        $this->con = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->db_name};charset=utf8", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass); 
        $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
        $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }catch(PDOException $ex){
        $this->catchError($ex);
        }
    }
```

is there any thing vulnerable in my connection? while i am providing other CRUD method in my class like this:

```
public function getRecordSet($sql,$bindVars=array()){
            $ary = array();
            try{
                $this->connect();
                $obj = $this->con->prepare($sql);
                if(count($bindVars) > 0){
                    $obj->execute($bindVars);
                    }
                else{
                    $obj->execute();
                    }
                $ary = $obj->fetchAll();
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                $this->catchError($ex); //Production Server: send exception through email 
                //echo($ex->getMessage()); //Developer Machine: Display Exceptions in browser
                }
                $this->con = null;
                return $ary;
            }//getRecordSet()
```

In this query users will retrive recordset as an array() using the following way for example:

```
        $sno = 1;
        $user_name = '%hussain%';
        $aray = array(':sno'=>$sno,':user_name'=>$user_name);
        foreach($crud->getRecordSet("SELECT * FROM users WHERE sno = :sno AND user_name LIKE :user_name",$aray) as $row){
            echo('<br>'.$row['user_name']);
            echo('<br>'.$row['user_password']);
            echo('<br>'.$row['date_reg']);
            }
```

Please let me know if there is anything goes wrong and makes my class vulnerable?

Thanks in advance.

Shah

Comment: Did you have any production server at hand before, which were sending an email on database error?

Comment: yes i have. but still i haven't got any error email...

Comment: How long does it running and what is traffic on it?

Comment: for last one two to three months and the traffic per day is apx: 70 to 80 users at a time.

Comment: well, when your db server will hang someday, you will see

Comment: This is the reason i am here to ask for help? what should i do to make it healthy? should i not use foreach loop?

Comment: foreach loop is all right

Comment: So, what's then going wrong? because i thought upon too many times but still i did not find anything which made me change the code?

Comment: just never make any code to send an email on error. for the overall site monitoring just use some external tool, like one from google. While all the error messages have to be logged. and you have to check error log regularily. Or, if it's a low traffic site, setup a watchdog script that sends you an email if error log starts growing.

Comment: after all, for some reason you are watching only PDO errors, while there can be many other - filesystem errors, memory errors, etc

Comment: Yes, that's a great idea. Thanks. And does anything wrong in my code which helps hackers for easy access?

Comment: Nope, I can see none in this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change function to

```
public function getRecordSet($sql, $bindVars=array()){
    $obj = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    $obj->execute($bindVars);
    return $obj->fetchAll();
}
```

however, it's rather matter of sanity, not security